# What to do when your CEO is destroying your startup?

Tags: startup, termination, leadership

I founded a mobile application company with 3 other people, three of us took 10% while one took 70% and the title of CEO. We were ok with this because it was his idea and he had the connections to get us funding initially.

Now a year later I am running the company in almost every regard except marketing and fundraising. Our CEO who is generally unfit for his job is now a detriment to the company (everyone who works with us or has worked with us agrees). If he left "peacefully" I could easily continue running the company and I would have the burden lifted of having to go through him day-to-day. If I left the company it would likely implode within a week if not sooner (this is a vital point and not an exaggeration, we are a small team and I run most technical parts of the company that no one understands).

What are my options in order to get the CEO out of day-to-day operations? He can keep his % or something close, but he is destroying our company by acting as its leader when he is clearly unfit. He doesn't realize he is hindering progress overall (doubt he ever could, he believes we have gotten this far because of his leadership and organization) but he does realize I am essential to the company moving forward.

It has gotten to this point because I have enabled him, I want the best for the company so I have given him the tools and knowledge to lead us this far. If I stop helping things fall apart, I am to blame and my work goes down the drain.

I have contemplated leaving many times to focus my efforts elsewhere, but friends and family are invested in our product and if we succeed I believe it will be a very worthwhile venture even if I need to put up with the CEO in some way.

Edit: I should have specified that our marketing consists of poor/ineffective social media marketing and our fundraising was brought in equally from friends and family. If our CEO was doing a fantastic job in those two areas, I probably would not be here.

Comment: Have you talked to the other owners of the company? There's a big difference between one person going to the CEO and saying "I think you should step back" and three people going and saying "We *all* think you step back".

Comment: @PhilipKendall yes everyone else agrees in private completely, although to some extent we are worried about the ramifications enough to deal with him up until this point. He already thinks the other two are disposable and has told me that personally.

Comment: The first sentence of your question is problematic. No, you alone did not found the company. The CEO and three others founded the company. You actually said "it was his idea".

Comment: @scaaahu Yeah, this jumped out to me in a huge way too. 10% is a tiny amount (relatively) - in every way this sounds like the CEO's company and this is essentially a mutiny.

Comment: "*Questions asking for advice on what to do are not practical answerable questions.*". This might also be a better fit for [startups.se].

Comment: @JoeStrazzere He clearly meant "If I stop helping him, things will fall apart"

Comment: What do you mean by "but friends and family are invested in our product"?

Comment: I'm sorry to say but you were screwed from the moment you took 10%. The title of the question shows whats wrong; it's not *your* startup anymore.

Comment: Even minority shareholders have rights that are protected in law though.  That's why movies that show a guy with 51% of the company being able to do whatever he likes annoy me.  You should consult a lawyer to find out exactly what rights you have in this scenario.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere What question though? OP hasn't specified what he actually wants to do. And your answer assumes that there is a board and that it's even possible for a 70% shareholder to be bypassed without destroying the company. I don't think this is answerable in its current state.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes, but you're making a number of assumptions and giving advice that is potentially disastrous in the OP's situation. And given that your answer boils down to "get everyone except for the CEO together and get rid of him" it's not much advice to work with. I doubt there *is* a general question here that can get multiple answers without them being impossible to compare in any meaningful way.

Comment: You have not clarified on the effect of fundraising on shareholding. It is it debt/equity? If it is substantial compared to the CEO's equity and you are sure to have investors on your side, you can discuss replacing him with the other founders. Is there some irreversible event that will happen if you stop operations for a few days? If not, you can consider leaving and then coming back as CEO if there's a partial shutdown after your exit.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere There is not even an indication what type of business entity we are talking about here, except that there is some guy who has assigned himself the title CEO. Actually, there is not even an indication which country we are talking about. And there is no indication what the legal status of the fundings and the partners is and what the 10% actually refers to.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> I am running the company in almost every regard except marketing and
>   fundraising.
>
> What are my options in order to get the CEO out of day-to-day
>   operations?

If you are a C-Level executive at a startup, you talk to members of the Board and the other founders, explain why the CEO must go, and talk about who should replace the CEO.

I worked at a small startup, and this was how the CFO ousted the CEO/founder and got himself moved into the CEO role.

Be careful here. Unless you can make a great case and unless you already sense that at least some members of the Board share your feelings, you might be betting your job on this move.

Comment: The only thing I would change in this answer is "you might be betting your job on this move" to "you *are*  betting your job on this move.  Excellent answer.

Comment: If he owns 70% of the company, wouldn't any such decision to replace him need to be approved by him?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I don't see how, in this case. The shareholders appoint the board. *Even if* the board fired CEO-Bob, Shareholder-Bob can just fire the board and elect himself to the Board. Then Charman-Bob rehires CEO-Bob who then fires Founder-Jerry. Further, Chairman-Bob can initiate a stock buyback from Founder-Jerry who must then negotiate its value, possibly in court or arbitration. Chairman-Bob then replaces Founder-Jerry and hires someone else, possibly giving him the newly repurchased stock as incentive.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm just speaking about the 70/30 split he talked about in the beginning. If the equity situation has changed then I agree but that's a pretty big detail to leave out.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere My point is that he'd still have to ultimately go technically willingly.

Comment: I like this answer because it gives 'probably' the best solution. One issue with us is that we have no board, we have gotten this far working between a couple of people. But I will speak with a lawyer and our other founders to try and come up with a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 29):

I hate to say it but it is his company. Your emotional attachment is remarkable, but does not change this. The owner of a car is the owner of the car even if he has no driving license and you have become a full-time chauffeur. As the one controlling the car you might feel that you are doing the major and most important work, but this is a fairly comfortable position to argue from if you sit in a car that you didn't have to pay for.

Your claim that he "only does marketing and fundraising" indicates that you might have no idea how difficult it is to get money for a mere promise of it being a good investment. People with great technical skills are a dime a dozen.

Comment: "People with great technical skills are a dime a dozen." No, they aren't. But otherwise: spot on.

Comment: Having worked in tech for over 20 years, no, people with great technical skills are not a dime a dozen.  The field is rife with idiots who pose as having great technical skills.  I've made a career out of cleaning up after these alleged geniuses.  People with ACTUAL great technical skills are a rare commodity.

Comment: "People with great technical skills are a dime a dozen." Simply not true.

Comment: People with *adequate* technical skills are a dime a dozen.

Comment: @RichardU I've met a lot more people with great technical skills than people with great *management* skills. It's all relative - what John is saying is that it's a lot easier to find technical skill than to find a person who can sell whatever these guys produce (which may or may not be true, depending on what they're actually making etc.).

Comment: @Luaan skilled people in any field are rare.  90% of people are faking it.

Comment: It isn't very useful just saying it is his company, I realize this and that's why I am here. The point is that we all agree that he is breaking the company, he doesn't realize this and if I left the company would almost immediately fail (I am sure of this so without going into detail it can be assumed). If you think my best option is to leave then that would be useful

Comment: Also, the point that people with great technical skills are a dime a dozen clearly shows that you do not understand the tech/mobile development industry.

Comment: Every employee considers him/herself irreplaceable. It's a law of nature. I've seen server admins who thought that they couldn't be replaced, because nobody else would understand how it all works together. I've even seen a developer who thought that naming all variables after fruits and vegetables would help in making him irreplacable.